# Is there a class for bootstrap to avoid 100% form

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to use bootstrap to put in a form but I want it to be 50% width in the centre, is there a way to do this without a specific stylesheet (using bootstrap classes only)

Comment: This is what the Grid is for.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how the question should be written, and edit your question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Utilize bootstrap 4's layout utility of grid. Like @Amy suggested, here is a link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

And here is an example:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4 offset-md-4'>
    <form class='form'>
    <div class='form-group'><label> name</label>
    <input /></div>

    <div class='form-group'><label>stuff</label>
    <input /></div>
    <button>submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```